# Getting data related through multiple models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I need some help with laravel relations. I have multiple models and I want to get results of one related trough others.

First model: Branch

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'branches';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Second model: User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function branches() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Branch');
    }
}
```

There is Pivot table branch_user

Third Model: Cars

```
class Cars extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cars';
    protected $primaryKey = 'car_id';
    protected $fillable = ['car_model_id', 'car_make_id', 'car_modification_id', 'car_registration', 'car_vin', 'owner', 'phone', 'branch_id'];

    public function make() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CarMakes', 'car_make_id', 'car_make_id');
    }

    public function model() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CarModels', 'car_model_id', 'car_model_id');
    }

    public function modification() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CarModifications', 'car_modification_id', 'car_modification_id');
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->make->name . " " . $this->model->name . " " . $this->modification->name;
    }

    public function branch() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Branches', 'branch_id');
    }
}
```

Here I want to get all cars available to user. (User can have multiple branches assigned).

```
class CarsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index() {
        $cars = Cars::all();
        return View::make('cars.list', ['cars' => $cars]);
    }
}
```

Hope you guys understood me. Should I use HasManyThrough or there is any other more correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see `hasManyThrough` relation in laravel and it will feed you.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through